# Open ID Connect for SSO adoption confusion?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

We have an enterprise application E, whose content is mostly a web application W. Here on wards, I will just use the Web application W for practical purpose.
Being a legacy system, this web application W has its own users, security, and access management. This means, it has its own login page, etc. Now this W is used by a government organization, and so will be hosted in the environment/network of this government organization.

This organization has already an OpenID Connect infrastructure, which is (supposed to be) used for all the applications that are hosted in their network/environment.

Now I need to implement single-sign-on feature in the web application W using this OpenID Connect infrastructure. Since W is basically not practically usable without having its own users and logins,
my plan is to create a mapping between the OpenID Connect user and the user of W first time, and move on with SSO.

This Web application W will be a client for the OpenID Connect server. Therefore, W will have client credentials with this OpenID Connect Server.

Let us just say, a user's id in OpenID Connect server is 'jadamso' (o for openid connect). And in W, the same user goes with id  'jadamsn' (n for native).

**Steps for my design**

1. The user 'jadamso' accesses web app W in a browser in this environment (through a URL). Let us assume that the user 'jadamso' has already signed into the environment using some other application.
2. The Web application W will ask for the authorization code from the OpenID Connect Server, by passing its client credentials
3. W will then ask for a access token (for the user's https session with W) from the OpenID Connect Server by passing in the auth code.
4. W will then ask for the user info of 'jadamso' from the userInfo API
5. If there is no mapping (corresponding user) found for user 'jadamso' in W user space, then 'jadamso' will be asked to login to establish the link (one time only). In our example, this will be mapping between 'jadamso' (in the OpenID Connect Server) and 'jadamsn' (in web application W).
6. If there is already a mapping, which is 'jadamsn', then W starts a web session as user 'jadamsn' in the browser
7. When 'jadamso(jadamsn)' clicks logout in W, we end the web session of W.
8. When 'jadamso' logs out of Open ID Connect server, then we may choose to end the web session of user 'jadamsn' in the web application W.

**Does this flow looks appropriate?**

I am not 100% clear on the whole thing, since this is the first time I am dealing with OpenID Connect (even OAuth 2.0 for that matter).

**Any other design ideas are appreciated!**

Comment: This sounds similar to using two emails for one identity against the W database. Once you establish originaluser@w.com is the same as anotheremail@x.com by having another authentication challenge, perhaps you can go one step further and prompt them to combine accounts, as a thought. The user could then be able to log into the same account in W using more than one email address.

Comment: do you know any java openid connect client library; i am trying to get google openid client library. hardly have any online documentation or materials. figuring out myself from the javadoc. getting challenging....